# Translate SQL to LINQ using LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I would like to know how to translate this SQL to LINQ...thanks in advance

```
DECLARE @Book table(
    BookId int,
    BookName varchar(50)
)

DECLARE @Author table(
    AuthorId int,
    AuthorName varchar(50)
)

DECLARE @Author_Book TABLE(
    --Id int IDENTITY (
    AuthorId int,
    BookId int
)

INSERT INTO @Book
(BookId,   BookName)
VALUES
( 1, 'Book1')
,( 2, 'Book2')
,( 3, 'Book3')

INSERT INTO @Author
(AuthorId,AuthorName)
VALUES
( 1, 'Author1'),
( 2, 'Author2')

INSERT INTO @Author_Book
(AuthorId,BookId)
VALUES
(1, 1)
--,(1,2)
,(1,3)
,(2,1)
,(2,2)
,(2,3)


SELECT * 
from @Book b 
left outer join @Author_Book ab 
             ON b.BookId = ab.BookId AND ab.AuthorId = 1
WHERE ab.AuthorId IS NULL
```

I have an AuthorId, and I have to select from "Book" table all Books that does not has association with this AuthorId in Author_book table...

Comment: refer DefaultIfEmpty() method to achieve your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
}

public class Author_Book
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
}


public class Example
{
    public void Linq()
    {
        List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
        books.Add(new Book { BookId = 1, BookName = "Book1" });
        books.Add(new Book { BookId = 2, BookName = "Book2" });
        books.Add(new Book { BookId = 3, BookName = "Book3" });

        List<Author> authors = new List<Author>();
        authors.Add(new Author { AuthorId = 1, AuthorName = "Author1" });
        authors.Add(new Author { AuthorId = 2, AuthorName = "Author2" });

        List<Author_Book> bookAuthors = new List<Author_Book>();
        bookAuthors.Add(new Author_Book { AuthorId = 1, BookId = 1 });
        bookAuthors.Add(new Author_Book { AuthorId = 1, BookId = 3 });
        bookAuthors.Add(new Author_Book { AuthorId = 2, BookId = 1 });
        bookAuthors.Add(new Author_Book { AuthorId = 2, BookId = 2 });
        bookAuthors.Add(new Author_Book { AuthorId = 2, BookId = 3 });


        var selectedBooks = from b in books
                            join ba in bookAuthors on b.BookId equals ba.BookId into ab
                            from a in ab.Where(x => x.AuthorId == 1).DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where (a == null)
                            select b;
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use above code, it is Linq implementation of given SQL.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this query:

```
var books = context.Books.Where(x => !x.Authors.Any(c => c.AuthorId == 1)).ToList();
```

or

```
var books = context.Books.Where(x => x.Authors.Any(c => c.AuthorId != 1)).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Wassmuss, thank you for your time and help....I have not access to "Author" inside the "Where"...

Comment: do you have relation between Author & Book tables in database?

Comment: if your database have no relation between Author & Book table, use this query :              var books = context.Books.Where(x => !context.Author_Book.Where(c => c.AuthorId == 1).Select(s => s.BookId)
                                                .Contains(x.BookId))
                                                .ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Try left join in LINQ using `DefaultIfEmpty()`. The code should look something like below :-

```
var a = from b in Books
    join a in Authors.Where(o => o.AuthorId == 1) on b.BookId equals a.BookId into joined
    from ba in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where ba.AuthorId == null
    select b;
```